# Adding OrderDetail to database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm making Coffee Shop app using .NET Core.

I have `OrderHeader` and `OrderDetail` entities. I created model classes for `OrderHeader` and `OrderDetail` and connect them using a foreign key. In the controller, when I try to save data to `OrderHeader`, for the `OrderDetail` noting happens.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ActionName("Summary")]
public IActionResult SummaryPost(ProductUserVM ProductUserVM)
{
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    OrderHeader orderHeader = new OrderHeader()
        {
            ApplicationUserId = claim.Value,
            FullName = ProductUserVM.ApplicationUser.FullName,
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now
        };

    _db.OrderHeader.Add(orderHeader);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    foreach(var prod in ProductUserVM.ProductList)
    {
        OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
            {
                OrderHeaderId = orderHeader.Id,
                ProductId = prod.Id
            };
        _db.OrderDetail.Add(orderDetail);
    }

    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Confirmation));
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Does orderHeader has Id, when you try to add it? Cause if you have autogenerated ids, it will be added in db, so ur code doesn't know it yet...

Comment: is there any reason why you can just do the save once with the header + header details?
Also you should show use the classes for the model and the code defining the `DbSet<OrderHeader>` and `DbSet<OrderDetail>`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of referring to the `Id`, you want to reference the whole object.

Add the `OrderDetail` as a collection to the `OrderHeader`.

```cs
public class OrderHeader {

  // other properties

  public virtual IColletion<OrderDetail> OrderDetail { get; set; }

}
```

And add the `OrderHeader` to the `OrderDetail`:

```cs
public class OrderDetail {

  // other properties

  public virtual OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }

}
```

If you've done this already, continue below.

Now instead of creating a new `OrderDetail` with the `OrderHeaderId`, add a reference to `OrderHeader` instead.

```cs
foreach (var prod in ProductUserVM.ProductList)
{
    OrderDetail orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
    {
        OrderHeader = orderHeader,
        ProductId = prod.Id
    };

    _db.OrderDetail.Add(orderDetail);
}
```

[Documentation on relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but see my models :

OrderHeader model

```
public class OrderHeader
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

    }
```

and OrderDetail model:

```
public class OrderDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }


        public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OrderHeaderId")]
        public virtual OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }


        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
```